# Assigning a double through scanner isn't reading the first input

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm currently writing a program for a class. The goal is to be able to have the user enter an integer, and initialize an array with that entered size. Afterwards, the program prompts the user for inputs going to each of those array slots ( grades as seen below ). We're also supposed to utilize a while loop when an input isn't valid. My issue is that when asking for the first grade, it requires two number inputs to loop through.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForWhile {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      int arraySize;

      System.out.print("Gpa Calculator");
      System.out.print("\nEnter total classes: ");
      arraySize = scanner.nextInt();

      double[] grades = new double[arraySize];

      for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

          System.out.println("Enter grade for class " + (i + 1) + ": ");
          grades[i] = scanner.nextDouble();

          while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
              System.out.println("Percentage grades only please!");
              System.out.println("Enter a grade for class " + (i + 1) + ": ");
              grades[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

This is currently what I have written, but in the console I would expect for an input of 2:

```
GPA Calculator
Enter grade for class 1: 90
Enter grade for class 2: 85
```

What needs to happen for it to progress is:

```
GPA Calculator
Enter a grade for class 1: 90
90
Enter a grade for class 2: 85
```

I've tried using scanner.hasNextLine() but not to much success, what am I missing? I also think my while loop condition isn't looping correctly, any input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking if there is a `double` to read **after** you have read the `double`. This,

```
grades[i] = scanner.nextDouble();

while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Percentage grades only please!");
    System.out.println("Enter a grade for class " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    grades[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

should be

```
while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    scanner.nextLine(); // consume the thing that isn't a double
    System.out.println("Percentage grades only please!");
    System.out.println("Enter a grade for class " + (i + 1) + ": ");
}
grades[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Huge help! This fixed all issues I had, I didn't realize that "!scanner.hasNextDouble()" wouldn't check the previous input, this makes a lot of sense, thanks!